# Postgres-XL cluster

Tags: clustering, postgres-xl

I'm trying to create a Postgres-XL cluster on 4 servers.  I've followed the recipe on https://ruihaijiang.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/postgres-xl-installation-example-on-linux/
(Note: update to *pgxc_ctl.conf* by adding `tmpDir=/tmp` and `localTmpDir=$tmpDir`)

I get to `pgxc_ctl init all` and then the following error:

```
postgres@ls $ pgxc_ctl init all
/bin/bash
Installing pgxc_ctl_bash script as /home/postgres/pgxc_ctl/pgxc_ctl_bash.
Installing pgxc_ctl_bash script as /home/postgres/pgxc_ctl/pgxc_ctl_bash.
Reading configuration using /home/postgres/pgxc_ctl/pgxc_ctl_bash --home /home/postgres/pgxc_ctl --configuration /home/postgres/pgxc_ctl/pgxc_ctl.conf
Finished reading configuration.
   ******** PGXC_CTL START ***************

Current directory: /home/postgres/pgxc_ctl
Initialize GTM master
bash: initgtm: command not found
bash: gtm: command not found
bash: gtm_ctl: command not found
Done.
Start GTM master
bash: gtm_ctl: command not found
Initialize all the coordinator masters.
Initialize coordinator master coord1.
bash: initdb: command not found
Done.
Starting coordinator master.
Starting coordinator master coord1
bash: pg_ctl: command not found
Done.
Initialize all the datanode masters.
Initialize the datanode master datanode1.
Initialize the datanode master datanode2.
bash: initdb: command not found
bash: initdb: command not found
Done.
Starting all the datanode masters.
Starting datanode master datanode1.
Starting datanode master datanode2.
bash: pg_ctl: command not found
bash: pg_ctl: command not found
Done.
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "197.242.148.228" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6029?
Done.
Done.
```

There seems to be more than one issue (`command not found` and `Connection refused`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the cause of the connection refused is a path issue. But it took me a long time and a lot of frustration.

**On all servers**

(GTM, Coord, Datanode1, Datanode2)

Edit `/etc/environment` (I got tired fighting with .bashrc) and add to the path

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin:
```

Then as postgres user/account run `pgxc_ctl init all`